# Android emulator with large storage (16GB) doesn't start

Tags: android, android-emulator, storage

I'm trying to start the android emulator with a large amount of storage (16GB) but it doesn't boot past the Android logo screen. I'm able to start the VM with less than a GB of storage though.

It doesn't display any error when it is blocked on the android screen, and it continues to display this logo forever.

the console output is:

```
C:\Users\Benoit>emulator: device fd:744

HAX is working and emulator runs in fast virt mode
creating window 0 0 438 729
```

the configuration file is

```
avd.ini.encoding=ISO-8859-1
hw.dPad=no
hw.lcd.density=213
sdcard.size=1000M
hw.cpu.arch=x86
hw.device.hash=2035627702
hw.camera.back=none
disk.dataPartition.size=16G
hw.gpu.enabled=yes
skin.dynamic=yes
skin.path=480x800
hw.keyboard=yes
hw.ramSize=768
hw.device.manufacturer=User
hw.sdCard=yes
hw.mainKeys=no
hw.accelerometer=yes
skin.name=480x800
abi.type=x86
hw.trackBall=no
hw.device.name=Custom Smartphone
hw.battery=yes
hw.sensors.proximity=yes
image.sysdir.1=system-images\android-17\x86\
hw.sensors.orientation=yes
hw.audioInput=yes
hw.camera.front=none
hw.gps=yes
vm.heapSize=32
```

I'm using HAXM and host gpu, 768M of memory, 800*480 resolution.

What's stopping the emulator from booting completely?

Comment: What does the console output say?

Comment: @Booger: added console output (nothing usefull sadly :( ), and configuration file

Comment: I meant the 'Console' Tab in eclipse.  Logcat might be helpful as well.

Comment: i don't know how to start a VM with eclipse, i've got the android plugin but i only know how to install and test an application

Comment: anything in logcat?:  (run 'adb logcat' from a terminal to see that output)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems like the problem only occurs when the virtual machine is launched from the AVD's UI. when launched from command line with `-partition-size 500` (or anything under 2048) it works as expected with the amount of storage set in the AVD's UI.

so launching my VM with `emulator @Smartphone -partition-size 500` is working. Hope it helps!